# Ordering output when using readdir()

Tags: php, readdir

I'm fairly new to PHP and have been using PHP's readdir() to look into a folder full of images and render them out dynamically based on how many images there are in that folder.  Everything works great, but one thing I've noticed is that the images are not displayed in the order that they appear on my local machine HD.

So my question to anyone who knows PHP is, is there way of using PHP to read the contents of a folder AND display them in order without having to rename the actual file names e.g. 01.jpg, 02.jpg etc etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readdir` likely just takes the file system order. Which is alphabetical on NTFS, but seemingly random on most Unix filesystems. The [documentation](http://de3.php.net/readdir) even says as much: »The entries are returned in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem.«

So you'd have to store the list in an array and sort that based on how you would like them to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Joey.  I'll have a look into storing them in an array as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function, it returns files alphabetically sorted by default:

```
$files = glob('/some/path/*.*');
```

Bonus, you can filter just images, and leave out directories.

Answer (score 0):

The php manual says:

```
string readdir ([ resource $dir_handle ] )
Returns the name of the next entry in the directory. The entries are returned in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem.
```

Meaning they should appear the same way.

More information found in [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php).

Comment: If they're looking with Explorer at a directory that has files named `1`, `2`, `10`, `1123`, `30`, etc. it will order them numerically. No file system would do the same on its own.

Comment: I didn't realize he wanted them in natural order. According to the question it looks like he want them to be sorted on the order of "which they are stored by the filesystem".

Comment: »The order that they appear on my local machine HD« is probably to understand as »the order in which they appear when I look into the folder with a file manager«. At least that and the hint that adding leading zeroes would solve it brought me to assume what I wrote above.

Comment: What I wanted to do was to have php look inside a folder sitting on the server that contains number of images.  Everything was going ok until I tested the script and noticed that the images were being displayed in a different order than they were on my macs os finder window.  For example on my mac, they would appear in order 01.jpg, 02.jpg 03.jpg etc etc, but php would display the images something like this 03.jpg, 01.jpg, 02.jpg.  So what I wanted to know was how to force the php script to order the images as I would look at them on my mac ie. numerically or alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Why not apply one of the [sort-functions of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)?

```
$files = readdir( $theFoldersPath );
sort( $files  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with in answer (together with the help of the people who posted) to my own question.

```
<?php 

$dir = "low res";
$returnstr = "";

// The first part puts all the images into an array, which I can then sort using natsort()
$images = array();

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while ( false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){
            $images[] = $entry;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

natsort($images);
print_r($images);

$newArray = array_values($images);

// This bit then outputs all the images in the folder along with it's own name

foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    // echo "$key - <strong>$value</strong> <br />"; 

    $returnstr .= '<div class="imgWrapper">';
    $returnstr .= '<div class="imgFrame"><img src="'. $dir . '/' . $value . '"/></div>';
    $returnstr .= '<div class="imgName">' . $value . '</div>';
    $returnstr .= '</div>';


}

echo $returnstr;
?>
```